# Precedence Confusion about <$> and <*> in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

Two examples both from http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors,

1). `(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5`

```
 (+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5, the 5 first got applied to (+3) and
 (*100), resulting in 8 and 500. Then, + gets called with 8 and 500,
 resulting in 508.
```

From the first example, it seems like `<*>` has higher precedence than `<$>`.

2).  `(++) <$> Just "johntra" <*> Just "volta"`

```
 (++) <$> Just "johntra" <*> Just "volta",   resulting in a value
 that's the same as Just ("johntra"++),and now Just ("johntra"++) <*>
 Just "volta" happens, resulting in Just "johntravolta".
```

From the second example, it seems like `<$>` has higher precedence than `<*>`.

So do they have the same precedence? can someone give me some explanations/references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<$>` and `<*>` has same precedence and left associativity. `$` has the lowest precedence of zero. You can use `ghci` to explore information about them:

```
λ> :i (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor’
infixl 4 <$>

λ> :i (<*>)
class Functor f => Applicative (f :: * -> *) where
  ...
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  ...
        -- Defined in ‘Control.Applicative’
infixl 4 <*>
```

Now you can work out the types to see how they typecheck.

Answer (score 6):

indeed they both have the same precedence (`infixl 4`: [`(<*>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) and [`(<$>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-)) and you can just read it from left to right -

```
(+) <$> (+3) <*> (*100) $ 5
= ((+) <$> (+3)) <*> (*100) $ 5
= (\ a b -> (a+3) + b) <*> (\ a -> a*100) $ 5
= (\ a -> (a+3) + (a*100)) $ 5
= 8 + 500 = 508
```

**remember** in this case we have `f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)`